# HtmlUnitDriver seems to be missing HTTP Components?

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit

To get started with Selenium2 and the HtmlUnitDriver I created a test project. As long as I'm using the FirefoxDriver, everything is working perfectly. But as soon as I switch to HtmlUnitDriver I get the following exception. Am I missing some dependencies? I found no documentation telling me which Maven dependencies I have to include, to get this working.

**Exception:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.createHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:536)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:500)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.setUseInsecureSSL(HttpWebConnection.java:711)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.setUseInsecureSSL(WebClient.java:1096)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.createWebClient(HtmlUnitDriver.java:263)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:172)
    at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.<init>(HtmlUnitDriver.java:168)
    at GoogleTest.testMe(GoogleTest.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1203)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1128)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1036)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 33 more
```

The project setup, **pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>de.test</groupId>
<artifactId>ui-tests</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <selenium.version>2.26.0</selenium.version>
    <testNG.version>6.1.1</testNG.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testNG.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <background>true</background>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop-selenium</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop-server</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Skip the normal tests, we'll run them in the integration-test phase -->
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skip>false</skip>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**A simple Test class:**

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class GoogleTest {

    private static final String SEARCH_BUTTON = "gbqfb";
    public final static String SEARCH_BAR = "gbqfq";
    public final static String RESULT_STATS = "resultStats";

    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        // does not work:
        // java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
        // org/apache/http/impl/conn/PoolingClientConnectionManager
         HtmlUnitDriver wd = new HtmlUnitDriver();

//        FirefoxDriver wd = new FirefoxDriver();

        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        wd.get("http://www.google.de/");

        WebElement searchBar = wd.findElement(By.id(SEARCH_BAR));
        WebElement searchButton = wd.findElement(By.id(SEARCH_BUTTON));

        searchBar.click();
        searchBar.clear();
        searchBar.sendKeys("Selenium Test");
        searchButton.click();

        WebElement resultsText = wd.findElement(By.id(RESULT_STATS));

        String resultsFound = resultsText.getText();
        wd.close();

        Assert.assertTrue(resultsFound.startsWith("Ungefähr 34.100.000 Ergebnisse"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT: fixed missing dependency!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try moving this block:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
    <version>${selenium.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

from the `<dependencyManagement>` section into the `<dependencies>` section of the POM (which is where you have the FireFox driver included).

Comment: Thanks I added the missing dependency, but still the same error.

Comment: I just tried to get it working by fixing the dependency defenition, but still the same error.

Comment: it seems that the parent project had conflicting depenencies. after isolating the ui-tests from other maven project everything works now!

Answer (score 3):

I got same error and here is how I solved - This error will come if your httpclient.jar, httpcore, httpmime jar files versions are not matching the parent 3rd party classes. I had httpclient-4.0.3.jar versions. Downloaded and added httpclient-4.2.jar to lib of my NetBeans. Similarly added httpcore-4.2.jar and httpmime-4.2.jar. The class executed!!
Download from following repository:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents

Comment: I'm using maven, so there is no manual download of artifacts!

Comment: Thanks. I wrote wrong version number in maven pom.xml file. After seeing your answer and fixed the version number, the issue was resolved.